# Showing Custom Message/Pop Up on Signing Page if particulate TextTab is populated with data

Tags: docusignapi

Is it possible to show custom pop up/message if particular TextTab/any field is populated by signer while signing the envelope?

Suppose Signer1 is signing Envelope1 and If he enters any data in "Notes" TextTab on page 4 - He should see on message like "You have entered notes, please take print out of this form and verify from supervisor".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to show a custom popup dialog during the signing session.  However, you could use another "Data Field" tab (TextTab) on the document to display the message -- and make that field conditionally visible based on whether or not there's text in the "Notes".

For example, here are the properties of a Data Field tab (TextTab) (shown in the DocuSign UI) for a field I've called "NotifyManager_Message".  Notice that I've included the text I want to show as **Initial Value**, specified that the field is "**locked**" (i.e., read-only to the signer), specified the **Font** as Bold and Red (so that the message will be clearly visible to the signer), and most importantly -- specified that this field is **Conditionally Visible** -- only shown when another field ("Notes") is populated.

[image: Data Field properties]

During the signing session, as long as the **Notes** field is empty, the message won't be shown:

[image: DS Signing Session - A]

But as soon as the signer types something into the **Notes** field (and moves focus out of that field), the message is shown:

[image: DS Signing Session - B]

Obviously this approach isn't exactly the same as using a popup dialog, but it effectively allows you to accomplish your goal.

To achieve what I've described above, the JSON for the two TextTabs would look like this:

```
"textTabs":  [
    {
        "documentId": "1",
        "pageNumber": "1",
        "xPosition": "100",
        "yPosition": "100",
        "width":"240",
        "tabLabel": "Notes"
    },
    {
        "documentId": "1",
        "pageNumber": "1",
        "xPosition": "100",
        "yPosition": "200",
        "width":"240",
        "tabLabel": "NotifyManager_Message",
        "conditionalParentLabel":"Notes",
        "conditionalParentValue":"##ANY##",
        "bold":"true",
        "fontColor":"darkred",
        "required":"true",
        "locked":"true",
        "value":"You have entered notes, please take print out of this form and verify from supervisor."
    }
]
```

Comment: Great, thorough answer Kim!

Comment: Thanks Kim. We are going with this approach.

Comment: Glad to help.  One thing to keep in mind as you decide on the text and placement of the message within the document(s) -- once visible, text labels like this will appear in the document(s) from that point on.  i.e., the message will appear in the signed/completed doc(s) - that's the biggest downside of this approach versus a popup dialog message (which as discussed, isn't possible with DocuSign).

Comment: @KimBrandl There is twist now. We want to show this message if user enters anything on page 4, but we dont want to print this message on pdf, if user wanted to print the document.

Comment: Unfortuntely not possible to achieve that within the DocuSign signing session.  A field can only be made conditionally visible based on the contents of ONE other field.  And, displaying a popup dialog message within the signing session isn't possible either (i.e., if you display a text message as described in my answer, it'll always appear on the doc itself).  Often times complex data validation use cases like yours can be facilitated by (you) building a separate webpage (outside of DocuSign) where the signer enters data (and your app validates the data before passing into the DS Envelope).

Comment: Thanks @KimBrandl. Actually we have sorted it out by using Note field. This field does not appear on pdf.

Comment: Glad that the Note field will meet your requirements okay.  Yes, the Note field will not show on the document itself -- it's just that you can't make it conditionally visible based upon the information the signer populates in the document -- it's always shown.